# Why does a route parameter in asp.net mvc 5 does not accept values "COM1" to "COM9"?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a blank asp.net mvc 5 application, and when I try the default route **/Home/Index/{id}** with any value (any string or integer value) it works ok, except for values **COM1** to **COM9**,

If I try to open **/Home/Index/COM1** for example, I get a 404 error.

Are this mvc reserved words? or what can be happening?

This is the controller and action:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

and this is the route configuration:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

    }
```

Comment: We need to see your route, the controller, and any values you're passing in. Are you passing in integer values? String values?  Give us all the data you allude to in your question.

Comment: It is reserved word in windows. Try to create `com1` file or folder.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker The controller, route and values are the default ones for the mvc 5 template

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov: So if it's reserved in windows I cannot use it in my mvc route?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems that asp.net mvc have some reserved filenames that are not allowed in routes:

http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/29/allowing-reserved-filenames-in-URLs.aspx/

This restriction can be bypassed by putting this in the web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```